# How to start working on open source projects

Tags: open-source-definition

I am about to graduate in May and have zero experience outside of school. The only thing worth putting on resume is I have been a TA for intro Java course for a year, and a 2 semester team project robot arm which turned more into a mechanical engineering project.

Note: I am a single father and have been working 40-60 hours manual labor a week since starting school, so I never had time to do an internship, or put time into anything not related to homework.  I wasn't just being lazy. :)

I finally have some help and have some free time to work outside of school. Now from what I have found on this and other forums was open source projects would be my best bet.  I would like to know what is the best way to start with this. I have tried to just Google this topic, and I was overwhelmed.

Also, I plan on setting up a github.  Would it be a good idea to add all the small programs I have done for algorithms and AI class? Sorting, searching, ect.. If so, should I do this in multiple languages? What else should I put on github? Will I be able to add open source contributions?

I know this has been asked before, but the main thing is I have zero experience in open source, and have no idea where to start. Hoping someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hi there! We generally thrive on specific questions, and this one is just a little bit "too many questions for us." It would be best to ask multiple questions highlighting a specific issue that you may be facing. Sorry about that! :D